# What kind of bug is it?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I really wonder what this is:

[image]

I find it near pound in Czech Republic (Central Europe). It's 2 inches long, AP. half wide. It was quite fast.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Coleopteran insect (Beetle order) in the Ground beetle (Carabidae) family. Based on the elytra (protective wings) and the dark first antennal segment, it looks like [*Carabus granulatus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carabus_granulatus). *C. cancellatus* is very similar, but has reddish first antennal segments. I don't think there are any other similar species in the Czech republic, but don't know the fauna there well. Overall, Carabus has many species and several are native to Eurasia and can be a size of 2 inches.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle#Wings

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carabus

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carabus_granulatus

https://www.insecte.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=160369

Comment: I agree, based on the european species I know of, it should be *Carabus granulatus*, *C. clathratus* or *C. cancellatus*. I suspect all of them are found in the Czech republic.

Comment: Scratch *C. clathratus*, which has pits between the elytra lines (instead of raised bumps). In my literature, the other two are separated by the color of the first antennal segment, which cannot be seen clearly in the picture.

Comment: I am so sorry. I wanted to do better picture, but it run away as soon as it noticed me. But I have a picture, where it can be seen (I think so). Anyway I didn't put it there in first place because don't have clue how to identify a bug in science way.

Comment: @user40760 The dark first antennal segment in your second picture says that it is *Carabus granulatus*. On *C. cancellatus* it is reddish in colour.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. I only bumped into this photo today. And sorry, guys. It is neither granulatus or cancellatus. This is a Carabus ullrichi. Without a single doubt. granulatus is narrow and elongated. Primary and secondary keels with cancellatus are more narrow. This one is convex, plump with very distinct keels.
Carabus ullrichi. For sure.

Comment: Can you add sources to your answer, and an image showing that it is indeed this speccies?